# Change color .val jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got input where is write text for example - `&1MyNicke&eName`.

Tag `&1` mean that, after tag `&1` all text need to change for blue color, tag `&e` mean that, after tag `&e` all text need to change for yellow color.

I dont have idea how to make it (maybe check each symbol), so my code now is:

```
<div class="namecolorchange">
    <center>
        <p style="color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Change name color</p>
        <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" class="nameinput" name="nameinput">
        <span name="namedemo"></span>
        <input name="namebutton" type="submit" class="namebutton" value="">
    </center>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "input[name='nameinput']" ).keyup(function() {
                var value = $( this ).val();
                $( "span[name='namedemo']" ).text( value );
                })
                .keyup();
            }
        );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regex to do this: I made a little example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1xp658hr/).

```
var replaceValue =  value.replace(/&1([\w]+)/, "<span style='color: blue'>$1</span>");
$( "span[name='namedemo']" ).html(replaceValue );
```

Demo for the **update**: http://jsfiddle.net/1xp658hr/1/